# How to find a standard text within a SapScript or SmartForm?

Tags: abap, sapscript, sap-smart-forms

I need to track down where within a large number of custom sapscripts and smartforms a specific standard text (SO10) is being used.

Apart from the equivalent of "check the code for each print script", I've not found a workable solution online. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting, I found a partial solution. The code below will search for a standard text within sapscripts, but not smartforms.

```
PARAMETERS: p_sttxt LIKE stxh-tdname.

DATA: BEGIN OF t_stxh OCCURS 0,
        tdname LIKE stxh-tdname,
        tdspras LIKE stxh-tdspras,
      END OF t_stxh.

DATA t_lines LIKE tline OCCURS 0 WITH HEADER LINE.

SELECT tdname tdspras FROM stxh INTO TABLE t_stxh
                         WHERE tdobject = 'FORM'
                         AND tdid = 'TXT'
                         AND tdspras = 'E'.

LOOP AT t_stxh.
  REFRESH t_lines.
  CALL FUNCTION 'READ_TEXT'
    EXPORTING
*       CLIENT                        = SY-MANDT
      id                            = 'TXT'
      language                      = t_stxh-tdspras
      name                          = t_stxh-tdname
      object                        = 'FORM'
    TABLES
      lines                         = t_lines
   EXCEPTIONS
     id                            = 0
     language                      = 0
     name                          = 0
     not_found                     = 0
     object                        = 0
     reference_check               = 0
     wrong_access_to_archive       = 0
     OTHERS                        = 0 .

  SEARCH t_lines FOR p_sttxt.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
    WRITE:/ t_stxh-tdname, t_stxh-tdspras.
  ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

This is a (fixed) version of the code found here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/179142

Answer (score 1):

What concerns SmartForms, you cannot. You cannot just find it like you want it.

Unfortunately, in such  ̶g̶o̶o̶d̶ ̶o̶l̶'̶  legacy technology as SmartForms everything is working legacy way, and standard texts are simply **hard-coded**. Yes, it looks awkward but they are really hard-coded, and these names are written out to SmartForm FM code every time it is re-generated.

[image]

So the only workaround here is to analyze the code.

1. Find all FMs for existing Smart Forms in system

There is a `D010INC` table containing all forms with their includes. The main point here is that all SmartForm FMs start with `/1BCDWB/` prefix.

The main logic is in the includes, so we need to find correspondent INCLUDE for the target form.

2. Fetch SF include source code

It can be done in a several ways: via `CL_RECA_RS_SERVICES` class, via table `REPOSRC`, but the simplest way is ABAP statement `READ REPORT`.

3. Search `SO10` text element name in the source code
4. Get Smart Form names for the FMs from hit list. It can be done via `STXFADMI` table, like in below snippet, but the more correct way is `SSF_FUNCTION_MODULE_NAME` FM
5. Bingo!

   Sample solution could look like this:

   ```
   DATA: lt_source     TYPE TABLE OF string,
         lt_smartforms TYPE TABLE OF d010inc,
         so_text       TYPE char50,
         fs_form       TYPE string,
         used_in       TYPE TABLE OF string,
         len           TYPE i.

   * populating the list of SmartForm FMs
   SELECT * FROM d010inc AS d
       INTO TABLE lt_smartforms
     WHERE master LIKE '/1BCDWB/%'
         AND include LIKE '/1BCDWB/%'.

   so_text = '85XX_FOOTER'. " <- our SO10 text element name

   LOOP AT lt_smartforms  ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_fm_name>).

   * reading FM source code
     READ REPORT <fs_fm_name>-include INTO lt_source.
   * checking if SO11 exists in source code
     FIND FIRST OCCURRENCE OF so_text  IN TABLE lt_source.

     IF sy-subrc = 0.
       len = strlen( <fs_fm_name>-include ) - 7.
   * searching for SmartForm related to the target FM
       SELECT SINGLE formname
         FROM stxfadmi
         INTO fs_form
         WHERE fmnumb = <fs_fm_name>-include+len(4).

       IF sy-subrc = 0.
         APPEND fs_form TO used_in.
       ENDIF.
     ENDIF.

   ENDLOOP.
   ```

Yes, it is junky, not elegant and awkward, but who said it should be so?