# How to find all SO10 text modules used in an SAP Adobe Form?

Tags: adobe, abap, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

How do I find all the text modules used in an Adobe Form? Is there a table somewhat like `TADIR` where I could type in the Adobe Form name and the object names (text modules) for that form name will appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348034/911419) regarding Smart Forms is perfectly valid for Adobe Forms too. Adobe Forms also have SO11 text elements hard-coded in the form FM code. The only difference is link between Adobe form FM and Adobe form INCLUDE: for some reason there is no link for them in the `D010INC` table.

However, as your intention is to find text elements of a single form, and not mass searching, you can find out the INCLUDE manually.

1. Find out Adobe form function module name. You can do this either manually (*Test* button in `SFP` tcode)

[image]

or via the `FP_FUNCTION_MODULE_NAME` FM. Resulting Adobe Form function module name should follow `/1BCDWB/SM0000XXX` pattern.

2. Open this FM in `SE37` and go to function group code (*GoTo->Main program*). There you will find something like this and there get the name of main INCLUDE, which holds the code.

[image]

3. Then by forward navigation go to INCLUDE code and by simple **Find** of `%textkey-name` pattern you can observe all text elements which were utilized in the form.

[image]